# Smooth numerical integration of oscillatory integrand

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

**How can I evaluate these integrals to get a smooth outcome for the ratio, preferably without any errors?**

I'm trying to integrate this:

```
f[x_, y_, a_, 
  s_] := (Cos[a*s*y/2])^2*(a^2 + 1)^(-1/2)*(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/
     2)*((a + x)^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/2) (Sqrt[1 + a^2] + 
     Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1] + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + y^2 + 1])^(-2)

nintf[a_, s_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  f[x, y, a, s], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity} ]

ratio[a_, s_] := 2*nintf[a, s]/nintf[a, 0] - 1 

ListPlot[Table[{a, ratio[a, 1]}, {a, 5, 15, 0.5}], Joined -> True]
```

For ease of reading, this is f:

$f = \frac{\cos^2(asy/2)}{\sqrt{a^2+1}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}\sqrt{(a+x)^2+y^2+1}\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+\sqrt{(a+x)^2+y^2+1}\right)^2}$

This gives me errors like so:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.005791102372788279 `and 1.7598057722389672`*^-7 for the integral and error estimates.

I tried using TrapezoidalRule, which gets rid of the errors, but when I use ListPlot, the graph of nintf is not as smooth. So then I just kept on using the function above because it gave smooth plots for nintf albeit with a long time and the above errors.

But hen I plot ratio[a,1] in the regime {a, 5, 15, 0.5}, Mathematica does not give a smooth graph despite giving smooth graphs of nintf[a,1] and nintf[a,0] in that regime. I just used ListPlot like above for all the graphs.

**Again, I am looking for a way to evaluate ratio, preferably without any errors. Thank you!**

Comment: What is `nintfcommnotrap` ? You haven't defined that in your code.

Comment: What are the parameter ranges of `a,s`?

Comment: @codebpr Sorry, edited to make it more clear.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann they are both real numbers, a is positive.

Comment: Calculating `nintf[3, 1]` in your notations, I obtained a warning "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." and a warning "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 18 recursive bisections in y near {x,y} = {-356929.,1898.59}. NIntegrate obtained 0.020228384449357567` and 1.563032080098117*^-7 for the integral and error estimates." and reasonable `0.0202284`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the integration subroutine as follows

```
nintf[a_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
Evaluate[(Cos[a*s*y/2])^2*(a^2 + 1)^(-1/2)*(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/2)*((a + x)^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/2) (Sqrt[1 + a^2] + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 1] + Sqrt[(a + x)^2 + y^2 + 1])^(-2)]
, {x, -Infinity,Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 6,PrecisionGoal -> 4] 

zw = With[{s = 1}, Table[{a, s, 2 nintf[a, s]/nintf[a, 0] - 1}, {a, 1, 5,.25}]]  

ListPlot[zw[[All, {1, -1}]],PlotLabel -> "s=" <> ToString[zw[[1, 2]]],  AxesLabel -> {a, ratio}]
```

[image]

Also `ratio[a,s]`seems to be smooth:

```
zw = Table[{a, s, 2 nintf[a, s]/nintf[a, 0] - 1}, {a, 1,5, .25}, {s, 0, 1.5, .1}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

ListPlot3D[zw, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, s, ratio[a, s]},MeshFunctions -> (#3 &) ]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know good numeric methods for multiple improper integrals. For example, `NIntegrate[
 Sin[x^2 + y^2]^2/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 4]` results in `33.0768` without any warnings/errrors, though  the integral diverges. Did you pay your attention to my answer where is proven the divergence?

Comment: The divergence can be establishing by switching to the polar coordinates: $\int_0^\infty \sin(r^2)^2r/r^2\,dr$ diverges and `Integrate[Sin[r^2]^2/r, {r, 0, Infinity}]` says "Integrate::idiv: Integral of Sin[r^2]^2/r does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.".

Comment: @user64494 I recognized your answer but couldn't follow your argumentation. You only showed that integral of the asymptotes diverges.

Comment: This implies the divergence  of the integral under consideration. Look at the result of `Series[(r*Cos[(a*r*s*Sin[\[Theta]])/2]^2)/(Sqrt[(1 + a^2)*(1 + r^2)]*
     Sqrt[1 + a^2 + r^2 + 2*a*r*Cos[\[Theta]]]), {r, Infinity, 
   2}] // Normal`.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused, this all evaluates well, but I get an error for the first ListPlot: ListPlot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of Null) beyond position 1 in ListPlot[<<1>>]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Comment: Counterexample  `nintf[0,0]` converges and is analytical solvable  `\[Pi] (-(2/3) + Log[9/4])`

Comment: @roamer There was a typo `.. ,, ..` in the first `ListPlot` command. Corrected!

Comment: Thank you for your help; I'm experiencing the same problem in the regime {a, 5, 15, .25}, {s, 0, 1.5, .1} where I have "Numerical integration converging too slowly" etc; even when I increase `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` to 100 I have this error but I'm sure this is not the right way to deal with it.

Comment: Try option `NIntegrate[...,, AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 6 , Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]`  . Now `zw =
 With[{s = 1}, 
  Monitor[Table[{a, s, 2 nintf[a, s]/nintf[a, 0] - 1}, {a, 1, 15, 1}],
    a]  ]` evaluates smoothly without error

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: I detected a typo when copy&paste in my code: it should be `(Cos[a*s*y/2])^2*(a^2 + 1)^(-1/2)*(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/
   2)*((a + x)^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-2)` instead of `(Cos[a*s*y/2])^2*(a^2 + 1)^(-1/2)*(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/
   2)*((a + x)^2 + y^2 + 1)^(-1/2)`. That leads to an incorrect conclusion. I'll delete my answer. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for your hint and the interesting discussion!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, it works within {a,1,15,1} but it doesn't work for non-integer values, like nintf[14.25, 1]; how could I evaluate it for these numbers?

Comment: @roamer For `a>14` the numerical integration seems to "fail" (message converging too slowly...). I checked the error for `nintf[14 + 1/4, 1]` and got `{0.000322614, 9.9137*10^-7}` for integral and error.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Do you know of a way to prevent this from failing?

Comment: @roamer Perhaps `IntegrationMonitor` is helpful, it shows integral and error-estimates. Your  integral seems to get smaller with increasing `a`, it's not so easy for the adaptive integration .